# Download PDF file, Angular 6 and Web API

Tags: angular, angular6, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to download PDF using Angular 6 and Web API. 
Here is the code implementation,

**mycomponent.ts**

```
download(myObj: any) {
    this.testService.downloadDoc(myObj.id).subscribe(result => {

        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(result);
        window.open(url);
        console.log("download result ", result);
    });
}
```

**myService.ts**

```
downloadDoc(Id: string): Observable<any> {
    let url = this.apiUrl + "api/myApi/download/" + Id;
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: "blob" });
}
```

**Web API Service**

```
[HttpGet("download/{DocId}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDocument(string docId)
    {
        var docDetails = await _hoaDocs.GetDocumentDetails(docId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var dataBytes = docDetails.Stream;
        var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StreamContent(dataStream)
        };

        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = docDetails.File_Name
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        return response;
    }
```

When I execute the above code, it is not downloading the PDF, here is the result object that is logged in the console

```
download result  
Blob(379) {size: 379, type: "application/json"}
size:379
type:"application/json"
__proto__:Blob
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are using .Net Core.

You return type is HttpResponseMessage. For .Net Core onward, it should be IActionResult.

So, in your case, you will be returning

```
return File(<filepath-or-stream>, <content-type>)
```

**Or**

You have to make one small change in your Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();
```

Then, I am not 100% sure here, but you have to change the routing too:

```
routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
```

Comment: Yes, I am using .NET Core, and your suggestion did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
declare var $;

@Injectable()
export class DownloadFileService {

   save(file, fileName) {
       if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        // IE specific download.
        navigator.msSaveBlob(file, fileName);
    } else {
        const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.setAttribute("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
        downloadLink.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, when i tried the suggested approach the document got downloaded as a json file. When I tried changing the extension to .pdf and opened it, got an error stating that "Reader could not open ''test.pdf' because it is either not supported file type".

Comment: U can use the service as following which will download the data as pdf itself
var yourPDFDataBlob = new Blob([response-got-from-server], { type: "application/pdf" });
downloadFileService.save( yourPDFDataBlob , pdf-file-name + ".pdf");

Answer (score 1):

In some browser, We need to dynamically create Anchor tag and make it clickable in order to download files. Here is the code .

```
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = filename;
  link.click();
```

Hope, this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**dataService.ts**

```
  downloadNoteReceipt(notes_purchased_id: number):Observable<Blob>{    
        return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + `receipt/notespurchasedreceipt/` + notes_purchased_id, { responseType: "blob" } );
      }
```

**component.ts**

```
  download(booking_id: number) {
    this.orderDetailsService.downloadNoteReceipt(booking_id).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      var newBlob = new Blob([res], { type: "application/pdf" });

      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
        return;
    }
     // For other browsers: 
            // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
            const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = data;
            link.download = "receipt.pdf";
            // this is necessary as link.click() does not work on the latest firefox
            link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));

            setTimeout(function () {
                // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
            }, 100);

    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

**component.html**

```
 <i class="fa fa-download" style="font-size:20px;color:purple" aria-hidden="true" (click)="download(row.booking_id)"></i>
```